# NSDateformatter (seems to) throwing an exception. But process does not exit with an error message and call stack

Tags: ios, string, datetime

Unfortunately, the Mac I'm working on does not allow us to attach a debugger, so I have no idea what the cause it.

Talk about a baptism by fire.

The tutorial program finds four placeholders and replaces them with text from four text fields.

```
NSString *stringTemplate = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:txtTemplate.text];
// My pseudo debugger
NSLog(@"%@", stringTemplate);


//Start Weird Exit
NSDateFormatter *dateShortFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [dateShortFormat setDateFormat:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
//End Weird Exit    

//Pseudo debugger
    NSLog(@"%@", txtPlace.text);
    [stringTemplate stringByReplaceingOccurancesOfString:@"<place>" withString:txtPlace.text];
   //txtDate is a TextField
    NSLog(@"%@", txtDate.text);
    [stringTemplate stringByReplaceingOccurancesOfString:@"<date>" withString:[NSString stringFromDate:[dateShortFormat dateFromString:txtDate.text]]];
   //There has to be a shorter way to type that. . .

    NSLog(@"%@", txtVerb.text);
    [stringTemplate stringByReplaceingOccurancesOfString:@"<verb>" withString:txtVerb.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", txtNumber.text);
    [stringTemplate stringByReplaceingOccurancesOfString:@"<number>" withString:txtNumber.text];
    txvStory.text =stringTemplate;
```

So I don't ever see the bottom four console messages. But I see the very first message though.

Like always, any improvements would be greatly appreciated. Anything from memory management to design principle advice.  Strangely, it is difficult to get a lot of advice in real life. But on the Internet, it seems to come left and right.

Comment: Try logging txtPlace, txtDate, etc. directly first to make sure they are non-nil before accessing txtPlace.text. Also, in your log statements do something like "txtPlace.text = %@" in your format string to be sure something prints out even if the text you are sending is nil.

Comment: @TimDean: good point about labeling my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've either got typos in your post, or your actually sending invalid messages to your date formatter. You have:

```
[stringTemplate stringByReplaceingOccurancesOfString ...
```

Where you should have

```
[stringTemplate stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString ...
```

In other words, there is no "e" in "Replacing"

Comment: Ah yeah, this was what was happening. Helps if I read the compiler warnings.